# Why does my Scala enumeration not work?

Tags: scala

I have the following Enumeration

```
class Market extends Enumeration {

  type Market = Value
  val ASX = Value("ASX")
  val LSE = Value("LSE")

}
```

In the same package but a different class I'm trying

```
if (Market.ASX = ...)
```

And I am getting a compile error not found: value Market

Comment: This is your 5th question in 2 hours- the previous 4 have been adequately answered and you've accepted none of them. Come on...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be an `object`.

```
object Market extends Enumeration {
  type Market = Value
  val ASX = Value("ASX")
  val LSE = Value("LSE")    
}
```

Comment: Mighty fast answering there! :-)

Comment: @Lachlan: I happened to enter the thread just after a few seconds it was posted.